# How to do a count query based on a day in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I was looking to find out how I can write a count query based on a user and day. For example if I have the following data:

```
Agent      | Date_1
Joe Bloggs | 06-jun-16 10:35:00
Joe Bloggs | 06-jun-16 10:36:00
Joe Bloggs | 06-jun-16 10:46:00
Joe Bloggs | 07-jun-16 09:36:00
```

I have been able to write the following:

My current query is the following:

```
SELECT
    AGENT
   ,DATE_1 
   ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AGENT ORDER BY DATE_1) AS COUNT_1    
FROM
    TABLE_1 
    ;
```

This gives a sequential count for every row based on my data. But I would like to show a count of only 1 for 06-jun-16 as the user is the same as well as the date, but I'm not sure how I can get that. What I would like is:

```
Agent Name | Date_1     | Count_1
Joe Bloggs |  06-jun-16 | 1
Joe Bloggs |  07-jun-16 | 1
```

The following is my create table and insert statement for my table:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_1   
   (      
"AGENT" VARCHAR2(12 BYTE),   
"DATE_1" DATE  
   );
```

Insert Statement

```
Insert into TABLE_1 (AGENT,DATE_1) values ('Joe Bloggs',to_date('07-JUN-16 09:47:23','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));  
Insert into TABLE_1 (AGENT,DATE_1) values ('Joe Bloggs',to_date('07-JUN-16 09:47:23','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));  
Insert into TABLE_1 (AGENT,DATE_1) values ('Joe Bloggs',to_date('07-JUN-16 09:47:23','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));  
Insert into TABLE_1 (AGENT,DATE_1) values ('Joe Bloggs',to_date('07-JUN-16 09:47:23','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));  
Insert into TABLE_1 (AGENT,DATE_1) values ('Joe Bloggs',to_date('07-JUN-16 09:47:23','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));  
Insert into TABLE_1 (AGENT,DATE_1) values ('Joe Bloggs',to_date('07-JUN-16 09:47:23','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));  
Insert into TABLE_1 (AGENT,DATE_1) values ('Joe Bloggs',to_date('07-JUN-16 09:47:23','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));  
Insert into TABLE_1 (AGENT,DATE_1) values ('Joe Bloggs',to_date('07-JUN-16 09:47:23','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));  
Insert into TABLE_1 (AGENT,DATE_1) values ('Joe Bloggs',to_date('07-JUN-16 10:07:47','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));  
Insert into TABLE_1 (AGENT,DATE_1) values ('Joe Bloggs',to_date('07-JUN-16 10:07:47','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));  
Insert into TABLE_1 (AGENT,DATE_1) values ('Joe Bloggs',to_date('07-JUN-16 10:07:47','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));  
Insert into TABLE_1 (AGENT,DATE_1) values ('Joe Bloggs',to_date('07-JUN-16 10:07:47','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));  
Insert into TABLE_1 (AGENT,DATE_1) values ('Joe Bloggs',to_date('07-JUN-16 10:07:47','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));  
Insert into TABLE_1 (AGENT,DATE_1) values ('Joe Bloggs',to_date('07-JUN-16 10:07:47','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));  
Insert into TABLE_1 (AGENT,DATE_1) values ('Joe Bloggs',to_date('07-JUN-16 10:07:47','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));  
Insert into TABLE_1 (AGENT,DATE_1) values ('Joe Bloggs',to_date('07-JUN-16 10:07:47','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));  
Insert into TABLE_1 (AGENT,DATE_1) values ('Joe Bloggs',to_date('07-JUN-16 10:16:48','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));  
Insert into TABLE_1 (AGENT,DATE_1) values ('Joe Bloggs',to_date('07-JUN-16 10:16:48','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));  
Insert into TABLE_1 (AGENT,DATE_1) values ('Joe Bloggs',to_date('07-JUN-16 10:16:48','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));  
Insert into TABLE_1 (AGENT,DATE_1) values ('Joe Bloggs',to_date('07-JUN-16 10:16:48','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));  
Insert into TABLE_1 (AGENT,DATE_1) values ('Joe Bloggs',to_date('07-JUN-16 10:16:48','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));  
Insert into TABLE_1 (AGENT,DATE_1) values ('Joe Bloggs',to_date('07-JUN-16 10:16:48','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));  
Insert into TABLE_1 (AGENT,DATE_1) values ('Joe Bloggs',to_date('07-JUN-16 10:16:48','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));  
Insert into TABLE_1 (AGENT,DATE_1) values ('Joe Bloggs',to_date('07-JUN-16 10:16:48','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));  
Insert into TABLE_1 (AGENT,DATE_1) values ('Joe Bloggs',to_date('07-JUN-16 10:32:31','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));  
Insert into TABLE_1 (AGENT,DATE_1) values ('Joe Bloggs',to_date('07-JUN-16 10:32:31','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));  
Insert into TABLE_1 (AGENT,DATE_1) values ('Joe Bloggs',to_date('07-JUN-16 10:32:31','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));  
Insert into TABLE_1 (AGENT,DATE_1) values ('Joe Bloggs',to_date('07-JUN-16 10:32:31','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));  
Insert into TABLE_1 (AGENT,DATE_1) values ('Joe Bloggs',to_date('07-JUN-16 10:32:31','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));  
Insert into TABLE_1 (AGENT,DATE_1) values ('Joe Bloggs',to_date('07-JUN-16 10:32:31','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));  
Insert into TABLE_1 (AGENT,DATE_1) values ('Joe Bloggs',to_date('07-JUN-16 10:32:31','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));  
Insert into TABLE_1 (AGENT,DATE_1) values ('Joe Bloggs',to_date('07-JUN-16 10:32:31','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));  
Insert into TABLE_1 (AGENT,DATE_1) values ('Joe Bloggs',to_date('07-JUN-16 10:33:35','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));  
Insert into TABLE_1 (AGENT,DATE_1) values ('Joe Bloggs',to_date('07-JUN-16 10:33:35','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));  
Insert into TABLE_1 (AGENT,DATE_1) values ('Joe Bloggs',to_date('07-JUN-16 10:33:35','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));  
Insert into TABLE_1 (AGENT,DATE_1) values ('Joe Bloggs',to_date('07-JUN-16 10:33:35','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));  
Insert into TABLE_1 (AGENT,DATE_1) values ('Joe Bloggs',to_date('07-JUN-16 10:33:35','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));  
Insert into TABLE_1 (AGENT,DATE_1) values ('Joe Bloggs',to_date('07-JUN-16 10:33:35','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));  
Insert into TABLE_1 (AGENT,DATE_1) values ('Joe Bloggs',to_date('07-JUN-16 10:33:35','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));  
Insert into TABLE_1 (AGENT,DATE_1) values ('Joe Bloggs',to_date('07-JUN-16 10:33:35','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));  
Insert into TABLE_1 (AGENT,DATE_1) values ('Joe Bloggs',to_date('07-JUN-16 10:49:20','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));  
Insert into TABLE_1 (AGENT,DATE_1) values ('Joe Bloggs',to_date('07-JUN-16 10:49:20','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));  
Insert into TABLE_1 (AGENT,DATE_1) values ('Joe Bloggs',to_date('07-JUN-16 10:49:20','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));  
Insert into TABLE_1 (AGENT,DATE_1) values ('Joe Bloggs',to_date('07-JUN-16 10:49:20','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));  
Insert into TABLE_1 (AGENT,DATE_1) values ('Joe Bloggs',to_date('07-JUN-16 10:49:20','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));  
Insert into TABLE_1 (AGENT,DATE_1) values ('Joe Bloggs',to_date('07-JUN-16 10:49:20','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));  
Insert into TABLE_1 (AGENT,DATE_1) values ('Joe Bloggs',to_date('07-JUN-16 10:49:20','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));  
Insert into TABLE_1 (AGENT,DATE_1) values ('Joe Bloggs',to_date('07-JUN-16 10:49:20','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));  
Insert into TABLE_1 (AGENT,DATE_1) values ('Joe Bloggs',to_date('07-JUN-16 11:14:17','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));  
Insert into TABLE_1 (AGENT,DATE_1) values ('Joe Bloggs',to_date('07-JUN-16 11:14:17','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));  
Insert into TABLE_1 (AGENT,DATE_1) values ('Joe Bloggs',to_date('07-JUN-16 11:14:17','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));  
Insert into TABLE_1 (AGENT,DATE_1) values ('Joe Bloggs',to_date('07-JUN-16 11:14:17','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));  
Insert into TABLE_1 (AGENT,DATE_1) values ('Joe Bloggs',to_date('07-JUN-16 11:14:17','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));  
Insert into TABLE_1 (AGENT,DATE_1) values ('Joe Bloggs',to_date('07-JUN-16 11:14:17','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));  
Insert into TABLE_1 (AGENT,DATE_1) values ('Joe Bloggs',to_date('07-JUN-16 11:14:17','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));  
Insert into TABLE_1 (AGENT,DATE_1) values ('Joe Bloggs',to_date('07-JUN-16 11:14:17','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));  
Insert into TABLE_1 (AGENT,DATE_1) values ('Joe Bloggs',to_date('07-JUN-16 14:08:13','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));  
Insert into TABLE_1 (AGENT,DATE_1) values ('Joe Bloggs',to_date('07-JUN-16 14:08:13','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));  
Insert into TABLE_1 (AGENT,DATE_1) values ('Joe Bloggs',to_date('07-JUN-16 14:08:13','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));  
Insert into TABLE_1 (AGENT,DATE_1) values ('Joe Bloggs',to_date('07-JUN-16 14:08:13','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));  
Insert into TABLE_1 (AGENT,DATE_1) values ('Joe Bloggs',to_date('07-JUN-16 14:08:13','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));  
Insert into TABLE_1 (AGENT,DATE_1) values ('Joe Bloggs',to_date('07-JUN-16 14:08:13','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));  
Insert into TABLE_1 (AGENT,DATE_1) values ('Joe Bloggs',to_date('07-JUN-16 14:08:13','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));  
Insert into TABLE_1 (AGENT,DATE_1) values ('Joe Bloggs',to_date('07-JUN-16 14:08:13','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));  
Insert into TABLE_1 (AGENT,DATE_1) values ('Joe Bloggs',to_date('07-JUN-16 15:31:05','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));  
Insert into TABLE_1 (AGENT,DATE_1) values ('Joe Bloggs',to_date('07-JUN-16 15:31:05','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));  
Insert into TABLE_1 (AGENT,DATE_1) values ('Joe Bloggs',to_date('07-JUN-16 15:31:05','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));  
Insert into TABLE_1 (AGENT,DATE_1) values ('Joe Bloggs',to_date('07-JUN-16 15:31:05','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));  
Insert into TABLE_1 (AGENT,DATE_1) values ('Joe Bloggs',to_date('07-JUN-16 15:31:05','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));  
Insert into TABLE_1 (AGENT,DATE_1) values ('Joe Bloggs',to_date('07-JUN-16 15:31:05','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));  
Insert into TABLE_1 (AGENT,DATE_1) values ('Joe Bloggs',to_date('07-JUN-16 15:31:05','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));  
Insert into TABLE_1 (AGENT,DATE_1) values ('Joe Bloggs',to_date('07-JUN-16 15:31:05','DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS'));
```

From the above data I am looking to count all the touches that are greater than 30 mins as a single count, anything that falls in between the 30 minute period doesn't increment the count.

From my data the first touch was 09:47:23 so that starts off as 1, second unique touch was 10:07:47 (based on next date period) which was roughly 20 mins later so count stays at 1, now looking at the 3rd distinct time, this was at 10:16:48 which was 9 mins later from the previous so the count would still stay as 1.

So in effect its a rolling 30 minute count based on the previous timestamp, if its below 30 mins count stays the same as previous if its greater count goes up by 1...

Hopefully that makes more sense.

Comment: Show us the whole query. And also the expected result.

Comment: You might need this .. `GROUP BY Agent,TRUNC(DATE_1)`

Comment: Why don't you expect the row with 07-jun? Do you need to filter your data?

Comment: sorry i do, just missed it out

Comment: Ok, So, what if you add a row `Someone else | 07-jun-16 10:10:10` to your data? what do you expect in this case?

Comment: if a new row is added, then becomes a new count for the agent as different agent

Comment: So the count is 1 always..? Probably, you should add more data to your sample.

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand. When will count_1 be greater than 1? can you give an example?

Comment: ok will add the rest of the table data to make it easier to understand, thanks guys

Comment: Is that a typo? Should the count for 06-jun-16 be 3, not 1? If it's 1 and not 3, then why? (That is, why is it called "count"?)

Answer (score -1):

This will give you the result you specify, a count of thirty minute windows for each combination of agent and date.

```
select agent
       , trunc(date_1) as date_1
       , sum(intvl)+1 as count_1
from (
    SELECT 
        AGENT
       , DATE_1
       , case when date_1 >= lag(date_1) over (partition by agent order by date_1)
             + to_dsinterval('0 0:30:0') 
          then 1 else 0 end as intvl
    FROM
        TABLE_1
   )
group by agent
       , trunc(date_1)
order by 1, 2
/
```

The LAG() analytic function allows us to compare the current value of DATE_1 with the preceding one, which is augmented with an INTERVAL() of thirty minutes to test the required window. Truncation removes the time element from the DATE_1 column, giving one result per day.

Comment: I have had a look and I have to try and workout that if their is another touch by the same agent and its within half hour then the count stays 1, otherwise if the next touch is after 31 mins to an hour then the touch moves up to 2 etc. So need to make the count for every rolling 30 mins. is this possible?

Comment: @user3191160: Your needed result is still unclear to me; can you please edit your question adding a wider example and some explanation of the logic you need?

Comment: reedited the above to include insert statement and create table.

Answer (score -1):

Its simple.just write a outer select statement like below:

```
select a.* 
    from 
    (SELECT
        AGENT
       ,DATE_1 
       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AGENT ORDER BY DATE_1) AS COUNT_1    
    FROM
        PROJECT ) a
    where a.COUNT_1  = 1    ;
```

Comment: This will not match the example that the OP posted; however, the real result the OP needs is still unknown to me

Comment: I could only understand that he already has the query and the resultset with count value as 1,2,3 and so on and he needs only 1st . So i posted my answer. Lets see if my understanding is correct or wrong.