# How to select values for count in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, count, case

thanks to a friend of mine, I have been able to obtain the following code that gives me a count of dates/times based on a difference of 30 mins. If the difference is less than 30 mins than the count stays the same otherwise if its greater than the count goes up by 1.

```
SELECT
CASE  
      WHEN DATE2 - LAG(DATE2) over (PARTITION BY NAME, TRUNC(DATE2) ORDER BY DATE2) <= 1 / 48  
        THEN NULL
        ELSE 1
      END AS COUNT1
FROM TABLE1
```

What I forgot to ask him to include was the values that have been counted as the start time and end time for that count as this will allow me to workout how long was spent, but I am not sure how I can add this based on the code above so not attempted anything.

I would appreciate if somebody could please advise on how I can bring something like this as sql is not my strongest point.

The following is some sample data:

```
NAME | DATE2
Humpty Dumpty | 21-JUL-16 09:27:24
Humpty Dumpty | 21-JUL-16 09:27:24
Humpty Dumpty | 21-JUL-16 09:27:24
Humpty Dumpty | 21-JUL-16 09:27:24
Humpty Dumpty | 21-JUL-16 09:31:31
Humpty Dumpty | 21-JUL-16 09:31:31
Humpty Dumpty | 21-JUL-16 09:31:31
Humpty Dumpty | 21-JUL-16 09:31:31
Humpty Dumpty | 21-JUL-16 16:42:03
Humpty Dumpty | 21-JUL-16 16:42:03
Humpty Dumpty | 21-JUL-16 16:42:03
Humpty Dumpty | 21-JUL-16 16:42:03
```

When I ran the above query I get the following:

```
Count1
1
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
(null)
1
(null)
(null)
(null)
```

which gives me the value but I also need to know the first value for when the 1 is counted and the last value before the next one is counted.

From the above my results should look like:

```
Count1 | Start_time | End_Time
1 | 21-JUL-16 09:27:24 | 21-JUL-16 09:31:31
1 | 21-JUL-16 16:42:03 | 21-JUL-16 16:42:03
```

One thing to point out is if there is another value for the same date within half hour, then the start time is also the end time..

Comment: Can you show some sample data as well?  It would make your question (and any answer) more useful to others who might face a similar problem.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - you can find sample data at OTN, where the original question was asked a few days ago. https://community.oracle.com/thread/3974725

Comment: @mathguy Thanks for the detective work, but the question should at least include some sample data here directly.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - no detective work, really; I believe what the OP shows is actually the answer I gave in that thread :-)  I agree though, the OP should have provided sample data here.

Comment: The answer "your friend" gave you is rather close to [the answer I posted](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39658692/146325) to your previous question. You should not waste peoples' goodwill in this fashion. Poor show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to identify the different groups.  Because you are using the `lag()` method, I will continue with that.  The next step is a cumulative sum, then aggregation:

```
SELECT NAME, TRUNC(DATE2), MIN(DATE2), MAX(DATE2)
FROM (SELECT t1.*,
             SUM(COUNT1) OVER (PARTITION BY NAME, TRUNC(DATE2) ORDER BY DATE2) as grp
      FROM (SELECT t1.*,
                   (CASE WHEN DATE2 - LAG(DATE2) over (PARTITION BY NAME, TRUNC(DATE2) ORDER BY DATE2) <= 1/48  
                         THEN 0 ELSE 1
                    END) AS COUNT1
            FROM TABLE1 t1
           ) t1
      ) t1
GROUP BY NAME, TRUNC(DATE2), grp;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon that works! just out of curiousity, how can I still add the touch count from the lag query to give me a total, or could I do a count based on the name, date and this would still give me the same figure

Comment: @user3191160 . . . I have no idea what "touch count" is.  New questions should be asked as questions not in comments.

Comment: Sorry its not a new question, its the initial case statement that gave me the count...

Comment: Assuming that each row in the original data is a touch then all you need to do is add COUNT(*) into the select list in Gordon's answer.  This will tell you the total number of rows between the start and end times

Answer (score 1):

```
DATE2
```

is the time on the current row - in the calculation this is the end time

```
LAG(DATE2) over (PARTITION BY NAME, TRUNC(DATE2) ORDER BY DATE2)
```

is the time on the preceding row (when ordered by date) - in the calculation this is the start time

It really is as simple as that.

I've updated the following to (hopefully) match your updated requirements.

Query A uses the LAG and LEAD functions to determine whether each row is at the start of a set of entries (previous row is > 30 minutes difference) or the end of a set of entries (next row > 30 minutes difference)

Query B then restricts the results rows that are either start or end rows (everything else is just noise)

Finally each start and end are joined together into a single row.

```
WITH
 test_data (name, date2) AS
  (SELECT 'Humpty Dumpty',TO_DATE('21/07/2016 09:27:24','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
   SELECT 'Humpty Dumpty',TO_DATE('21/07/2016 09:27:24','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
   SELECT 'Humpty Dumpty',TO_DATE('21/07/2016 09:27:24','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
   SELECT 'Humpty Dumpty',TO_DATE('21/07/2016 09:27:24','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
   SELECT 'Humpty Dumpty',TO_DATE('21/07/2016 09:31:31','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
   SELECT 'Humpty Dumpty',TO_DATE('21/07/2016 09:31:31','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
   SELECT 'Humpty Dumpty',TO_DATE('21/07/2016 09:31:31','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
   SELECT 'Humpty Dumpty',TO_DATE('21/07/2016 09:31:31','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
   SELECT 'Humpty Dumpty',TO_DATE('21/07/2016 09:40:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
   SELECT 'Humpty Dumpty',TO_DATE('21/07/2016 09:40:00','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
   SELECT 'Humpty Dumpty',TO_DATE('21/07/2016 16:42:03','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
   SELECT 'Humpty Dumpty',TO_DATE('21/07/2016 16:42:03','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
   SELECT 'Humpty Dumpty',TO_DATE('21/07/2016 16:42:03','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
   SELECT 'Humpty Dumpty',TO_DATE('21/07/2016 16:45:03','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
   SELECT 'Humpty Dumpty',TO_DATE('21/07/2016 16:45:03','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
   SELECT 'Humpty Dumpty',TO_DATE('21/07/2016 18:00:03','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
   SELECT 'Humpty Dumpty',TO_DATE('21/07/2016 18:00:03','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
   SELECT 'Humpty Dumpty',TO_DATE('21/07/2016 18:00:03','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
   SELECT 'ABC',TO_DATE('21/07/2016 18:00:03','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
   SELECT 'ABC',TO_DATE('21/07/2016 18:10:03','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
   SELECT 'ABC',TO_DATE('21/07/2016 18:50:03','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL UNION ALL
   SELECT 'ABC',TO_DATE('21/07/2016 18:51:03','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') FROM DUAL
 )
SELECT
 name
,TO_CHAR(start_time,'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')     start_time
,TO_CHAR(end_time,'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')       end_time
FROM
 --Query B
 (SELECT
   name
  ,date2                                      start_time
  ,LEAD(date2) OVER (PARTITION BY name,TRUNC(date2) ORDER BY date2)   end_time
  ,start_flag
  FROM
   --Query A
   (SELECT
     name
    ,date2
    ,CASE
      WHEN date2 - LAG(date2) OVER (PARTITION BY name, TRUNC(date2) ORDER BY date2) <= (1/48)
       THEN 'N'
      ELSE 'Y'
     END                                        start_flag
    ,CASE
      WHEN LEAD(date2) OVER (PARTITION BY name, TRUNC(date2) ORDER BY date2) - date2 <= (1/48)
       THEN 'N'
      ELSE 'Y'
     END                                        end_flag
    FROM
     test_data
    ORDER BY
     name
    ,date2
   )
  WHERE 1=1
  AND (start_flag = 'Y' OR end_flag = 'Y')
  )
WHERE start_flag = 'Y'
;
```

Comment: Thanks Christian, I have written the query gave along with the case statement for the touches but for some reason, (sample data) the first value is not included and I get the start time 09:31:31 and end time as 16:42:03..

Comment: Gordon's answer below is a better answer so I've given it a plus 1